# LightDM and the need for a greeter in set-top box environment

Tags: lightdm

Lightdm can be used in a set-top box environment, ie starting a configured X session as a configured user; in this case all data will be retrieved from the config file.

Can lightdm work/be installed without any greeter, to minimise the footprint on such a minimal system?

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, nodm was specifically designed to address this use case.  I'm unsure of present development status there.

Comment: uxlaunch is the Ubuntu's answer for that as well, but it's not completely integrated with Plymouth yet. LightDM being the next standard supports Plymouth well already.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LightDM can run without any greeter.  Set LightDM to automatically log in as the user / session required.

If you log out of the session however LightDM will try and start a greeter.  This is planned to be fixed, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/812170 .